# Can I use a switch statement to manage my forms in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement

I learnt to build form with React by create a handle function for every input elements

```
handleChangeName = (e: any) => {
    this.setState({
        name: e.target.value
    })
}

handleChangeSurname = (e: any) => {
    this.setState({
        surname: e.target.value
    })
}
```

But I think that my code would be clearer if I only use one function with a switch inside that handle every case, like this:

```
handleChange = (e: any) => {
      switch (e.target.id) {
        case 'name':
            this.setState({
                name: e.target.value
            })
            break;
        case 'surname':
            this.setState({
                surname: e.target.value
            })
            break;
      }
}
```

Is it still a good practice for React? Are there any drawbacks I wouldn't think of?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need a switch case, you can use a [Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```
handleChange = (e: any) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id]: e.target.value
        })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's even better! I just found a 'drawback' to this method (and the switch one), if you mistype your id, you will not receive any error and your form will not correctly works.